# Show that the intersection of two probabilities in a certain interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning

I am struggeling with the following problem:

> Suppose that $P(A)= \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(B)= \frac{1}{3}$. Show that
>   $\frac{1}{12} \leq P(A \cap B) \leq \frac{1}{3} $.

Basically I try to show this for the upper and lower bound. For the lower bound I just take $min (P(A), P(B) )$. However I am struggeling with the upper bound.

I really appreciate your answers!

Comment: You'll take $\min\{P(A),P(B)\}$ for the upper bound, not the lower. This is because $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$. The probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening, couldn't be more than the probability of the less probable between $A$ and $B$, since we want both $A$ and $B$ to be happening.

Comment: It should be intersection of two events, not two probabilities!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You have probably seen the formula $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$. Note that $\Pr(A\cup B)\le 1$.

Comment: Thx! However I am getting $0$ because: $-\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{3} + (\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{3})$. What am I doing wrong? The last term I get from the axiom of countable additivity.

Comment: Using the hint above, we get $\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\Pr(A\cap B)\le 1$. Do some algebra. We get $\Pr(A\cap B)\ge \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-1=\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Axiom of additivity says that if $X$ and $Y$ are *mutually exclusive* then $\Pr(X\cup Y)=\Pr(X)+\Pr(Y)$. In our case $A$ and $B$ cannot be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thx a lot. I understand it completely now!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that $1/3$ is an *upper* bound and $1/12$ is a *lower* bound. And we can give examples where the upper bound is attained. You more or less explained why. similarly, there are examples where the lowe bound is attained. All we need to do is make sure that $A\cup B$ is the full universe.